# Browser OnLoad event handler

Tags: ajax, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have made an google chrome extension recently. It is working fine except that it works only when user clicks it. I want it to update status even if it is not clicked. So, there is any browser onload action so that I can start updating the status continuously using AJAX.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a background page for your extension.

The [background page](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/background_pages.html) is loaded as soon as the extension is enabled, so any code in your background page will get executed without needing the user to click anything.

Comment: Thanks I was searching for something like this :)

Comment: Yes, you will need to declare the filename of your background page in your `mainfest.json` file, if that's what you mean? http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/background_pages.html#manifest